# Neo4j showing error on switching versions

Tags: java, neo4j

I am having my java program for Neo4j with the Neo4j version as 2.3.0m1 .The jar files i was using for the connect was neo4j-desktop-2.3.0-M01.jar . Everything works fine. Now i want to load databases from 2.3.0-m3 version which is not opening in the current version. I am not able to find any jar files for this new version either .

This is my java code

```
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Relationship;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;


public class Testing {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    System.out.println("hai");

    GraphDatabaseFactory dbFactory = new GraphDatabaseFactory();
    GraphDatabaseService db= dbFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase("D:\\graph.db");

    try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {
        System.out.println("began transaction");

        tx.success();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
       System.out.println("Done successfully");

}
}
```

This is the error i am getting if i try to open a higher version db (from 2.3.0-M3)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, D:\data2\graph.db
at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:314)
at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:59)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:107)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:94)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:176)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:66)
at Testing.main(Testing.java:19)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager@258bb6ba' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:499)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:108)
at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:309)
... 6 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource@f1cb476' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:499)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:108)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataSourceManager.java:117)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:493)
... 8 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader$UpgradingStoreVersionNotFoundException: 'neostore.nodestore.db' does not contain a store version, please ensure that the original database was shut down in a clean state.
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.UpgradableDatabase.checkUpgradeable(UpgradableDatabase.java:86)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreMigrator.needsMigration(StoreMigrator.java:158)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader.getParticipantsEagerToMigrate(StoreUpgrader.java:259)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader.migrateIfNeeded(StoreUpgrader.java:134)
at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.upgradeStore(NeoStoreDataSource.java:532)
at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:434)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:493)
... 11 more
```

Also i am trying to download the enterprise version zip(2.3.0-M1) for windows from neo4j web site because i have the import-graphml feature in 2.3.0-M3 for which i want to move up to 2.3.0-M3.But the link provided in neo4j site is not downloading it completly.
http://neo4j.com/artifact.php?name=neo4j-enterprise-2.3.0-M01-windows.zip
Is there somewhere else this can be downloaded from

Comment: the best practices when writing code in java using neo4j embedded, is to have a proper build system / dependency management system in place. Conside using gradle or maven for this - so you don't have to mess around with downloads.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing upgrade of Neo4j you also need to upgrade database version.

**neo4j.properties**

```
# Enable this to be able to upgrade a store from an older version.
allow_store_upgrade=true
```